# Shadow mapping with arbitrary number of meshes and lights

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, shadow-mapping

I am developing a 3D engine with WebGL and I am trying to implement shadows. My logic is as follow:

The first time that scene is rendered I loop over all meshes and create and compile the shader program (vertex and fragment shader). I only have one shader program per mesh, so, when the shader is created I need to know the lights that has the scene, the mesh's material and other considerations.

Once the shader is created I attached it to the mesh object and render the object. In the next iteration the shader is not created (because it was created previously).

I heard about shadow mapping. In order to implement it I need to render to texture and compute the distance between the light and the current fragment and this for each light source. So if I have 2 lights I need to do this process twice and then pass those textures to the shader that render the scene.

The problem is that I can create 100 ligths if I want and I would need to render 100 textures and pass it to the shader that render the scene, but OpenGL and WebGL has a limited unit textures, so I couldn't bind all textures to render the complete scene.

How can I implement shadow mapping with an arbitrary number of lights?

Comment: You are correct. This is why forward rendering systems generally don't support 100 lights per mesh. They support around 4 in general and each object uses only the 4 closest or most important or some other metric to decide which 4 of 100s of lights to use. The other common option is to use [deferred rendering](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/01/webgl-deferred-shading/) which more easily supports more lights per mesh

Comment: So, a possible solution would be compute the distance between mesh and light and get the X closer lights for that mesh. Right? In this case I need to compile the shader each time that mesh position change.

Comment: Yes that would be a possible solution. It's not clear to me why you have one shader per mesh. Most programs that generate shaders make one shader per combination of needs. So for example one shader with 1 light, one shader with 2 lights, one shader with 3 lights, one with 4 (stop there if limited to 4). They might have one with each combination of point light, directional light, and spot light. But, they don't have one per mesh. If 2 meshes have the same needs they use the same shader. The other option is an *uber shader* with lots of options. That's easier but slower to render.

Comment: Maybe I don't explain well. Yes, I have only one shader per mesh, but that shader is created at runtime, I mean if the mesh has lambert material I added code for lambert material and only for lambert material (and not for Phong or Blinn material). If the scene has only one Point light I include in runtime code for one light point in the shader. So I only have 1 shader per mesh but that shader only contains the code needed for the mesh.

Comment: My point was if Object#3 and Object#5 both need the same shader features they should use the same shader. In other words if Object#3 and Object#5 are both "lambert and 1 point light" then they should use the same shader. If Object#9 and Object17# need "phong and 2 spot lights" they also share a shader. At least that's what most engines do AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I have a shader cache, once that shader is created if then I need to render another mesh with the same needed I re-use the previous shader